# SQL Server : how to select last 3 rows in the table ordered by desc and then sort them asc?

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

I have a CTE with the last 3 rows of the table sorted by `VersionNumber DESC`. How I can sort them backwards in order to have the smallest `VersionNumber` from those 3 always to have display order 1?

There is no `LIMIT` in Microsoft SQL Server...

```
;WITH cte AS
(       
    SELECT  
        BSId, RevisedBSId, VersionNumber, 
        RANK() OVER (ORDER BY VersionNumber DESC) AS [DisplayOrder] 
    FROM
        cte
),
sortedctethree AS
(
    SELECT TOP 3 
        BSId, RevisedBSId, VersionNumber, DisplayOrder 
    FROM 
        sortedcte
)
SELECT *
FROM sortedctethree
```

Here `DisplayOrder` is wrong. If I use another CTE where I am trying to reorder, it is still wrong.

I need only 3 rows. But in the TOP 3 can be also one, or two rows in the result. I need in that case always have the `DisplayOrder` 1 for the smallest VersionNumber.

```
VersionNumber | DisplayOrder 
--------------+--------------
     2        |      2
     1        |      1
```

How it is possible to achieve? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2):

try like below you dont need another cte

```
WITH cte AS
    (       
    SELECT  
       BSId, RevisedBSId, VersionNumber, 
        rank() OVER (ORDER BY VersionNumber DESC)  AS [DisplayOrder] from 
     table_name
)      
        SELECT  BSId, RevisedBSId, VersionNumber , DisplayOrder FROM cte
        where DisplayOrder<=3
        order by DisplayOrder
```

Comment: No, looks it is not what I need. I need the smallest  version number from the last three biggest to be always 1.

Comment: Select top 3 can be 

`VN DisplayOrder
99 3
98 2
97 1


VN DisplayOrder
2 2
1 1

VN DisplayOrder
1 1
`

Comment: @Erlica could you please sample data in your question description

Comment: `VN DisplayOrder
3 3
2 2
1 1

VN DisplayOrder
4 3
3 2
2 1`

Comment: order by DisplayOrder desc would work if only the problem is ordering

Answer (score 0):

You may try with the next approach. Number your data using [DENSE_RANK()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) ordered by `VersionNumber` descending and then select first three rows and order them ascending:

```
;WITH cte AS (       
    SELECT  
        BSId, 
        RevisedBSId, 
        VersionNumber, 
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY VersionNumber DESC) AS [DisplayOrder] 
    FROM YourTable
)
SELECT  
    BSId, 
    RevisedBSId, 
    VersionNumber
FROM cte
WHERE [DisplayOrder] <= 3
ORDER BY VersionNumber ASC
```

Comment: I found the issue.  Rank() OVER (ORDER BY VersionNumber DESC) is not working together with TOP correctly. If I put DisplayOrder <= 3, it is working.

Comment: @Erlica use `DENSE_RANK` if you have more than one row for one `VersionNumber`. In your case `TOP 3` works if you include `ORDER BY DisplayOrder ASC`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly:

If you use ROW_NUMBER() with data ordered asc then the smallest value will have DisplayOrder = 1

```
;WITH cte AS
(       
    SELECT  
        BSId, RevisedBSId, VersionNumber, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY VersionNumber ASC) AS [DisplayOrder] 
    FROM
        cte
)
    SELECT TOP 3 
        BSId, RevisedBSId, VersionNumber, DisplayOrder 
    FROM 
        sortedcte where [DisplayOrder] =1
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are no partitions this is the simplest way, you dont need rank or row_number in your subquery or CTE

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY VersionNumber) as DisplayOrder, VesionNumber FROM (
    SELECT TOP 3 VesionNumber from mytable
    ORDER BY VesionNumber DESC
) A 
ORDER BY VesionNumber ASC
```

Or using your approach

```
;WITH cte AS
(       
    SELECT  
        BSId, RevisedBSId, VersionNumber, 
        RANK() OVER (ORDER BY VersionNumber DESC) AS [SelectOrder], 
        RANK() OVER (ORDER BY VersionNumber ASC) AS [DisplayOrder], 
    FROM
        cte
),
sortedctethree AS
(
    SELECT TOP 3 
        BSId, RevisedBSId, VersionNumber, DisplayOrder, SelectOrder
    FROM 
        sortedcte
    ORDER BY SelectOrder
)
SELECT *
FROM sortedctethree
ORDER BY DisplayOrder
```